# Solving a multiple choice question paper

Tags: probability

Firstly, I am not sure whether this is a mathematical problem. Please inform me in case it is not.
My question is as follows

I have a online game with 14 questions. It's a kind of treasure hunt. Each question has 4 choices. The correct answer choices are unevenly distributed.
Choices B & C constitute 5 answers each and choice A & D constitute 2 answers each.

Imagine a man without any knowledge about the quiz subject, what would be the best way to clear the quiz to go to the next level?
Once the user submits the answers, the system gives him reference links for questions he answered wrongly. But they will not be numbered and he will not know which references are for which question. The references will be in order and the user has unlimited attempts to crack the paper.
The user has to get 10 answers correct to crack the quiz. What is the best approach to follow to go to next level. 
The problem is a practical problem and I am not sure under which topic of mathematics this falls under.

Comment: how many attempts does the man have? unlimited?

Comment: yes unlimited attempts

Comment: This is similar to the code-breaking game [Mastermind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_%28board_game%29) and I suspect you will want similar types of algorithm to solve it

Answer (score 1):

Answered by [Henry](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6460/henry%20Henry).

This is similar to the code-breaking game [Mastermind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_%28board_game%29) and I suspect you will want similar types of algorithm to solve it – Henry Sep 6 '12 at 20:04

Comment: this links to the page for Henry and a wiki page for mastermind, could you put a link to how to solve the game?

Comment: I appreciate the sentiment of getting a question off of the unanswered queue, but I concur with Amzoti; each answer should be relatively stand alone, even if all the links therein break.